# How to get id of the anchor tag in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, anchor

Hi I am developing Angularjs application. I have dynamically generated anchor tag. In anchor tag i am binding img only. So based on the img src clicked i want some computations.

```
 <div class="language">
            <a href="#">
                <img ng-src="images/{{ lang === 'ar-sa' ? 'arabic.png' : 'en-english-language-browser-function-512.png' }}" />
            </a>
        </div>
```

This is my controller code.

```
 if ($scope.lang === 'ar-sa')
    {
        $translate.use('de_AR');
    }
    else
    {
        $translate.use('de_EN');
    }
```

Whenever i click on img i want to get that img name in controller. So that i can apply some computation like if use clicked on arabic.png then i can covert page to arabic. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: What, do you mean `ng-click="myFunc( 'images/' + (lang === 'ar-sa' ? 'arabic.png' : 'en-english-language-browser-function-512.png') )"`?

Comment: have u generated the anchor tags using ng-repeat ??

Comment: No just two anchor tags. Hardcoded as above. Thanks

Comment: `like if use clicked on arabic.png then i can covert page to arabic` instead of doing it like this, use `$translate` and `translate` filter wherever you have text and `$translate.use('de_EN')` will automatically convert whole page into selected language

Comment: Yes if i click on arabic.png then  i want to call $translate.use('de_AR')

Comment: Trivial with ngClick.

Comment: @NiranjanGodbole Let me see if I understand correctly - You have a button that when clicked it will toggle the languages (Arabic/English). What you're trying to do is to change the image in that button **AND** also the translation based on the selected language?

Comment: Yes exactly. Thanks. I am checking default language of browser. If the default language is Arabic then i am binding English.png image so that he can switch to English.  $scope.lang = $window.navigator.language || $window.navigator.userLanguage;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is to add a function that change the language on the controller:

```
$scope.lang = null; // Default language
$scope.changeLanguage = function() {
    $scope.lang = $scope.lang == 'de_AR' ? 'de_EN' : 'de_AR'; // Change the language based on the current selected
    $translate.use($scope.lang);
}
$scope.changeLanguage(); // Set language when the controller loads
```

Next, in your view, you just need to call this function:

```
<div class="language">
    <a href="#" ng-click="changeLanguage()">
       <img ng-src="images/{{ lang === 'de_AR' ? 'arabic.png' : 'en-english-language-browser-function-512.png' }}" />
    </a>
</div>
```

As an alternative, you can also pass the selected language:

```
$scope.changeLanguage = function( lang ) {
    $scope.lang = lang;
    $translate.use($scope.lang);
}
$scope.changeLanguage('de_AR');
```

And in the view:

```
<div class="language">
    <a href="#" ng-click="changeLanguage(lang === 'de_AR' ? 'de_EN' : 'de_AR')">
       <img ng-src="images/{{ lang === 'de_AR' ? 'arabic.png' : 'en-english-language-browser-function-512.png' }}" />
    </a>
</div>
```

**Edit:**

Since your default language is [based on browser setting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43493019/dynamic-language-selection-in-angularjs/43493249#43493249), you can do the following:

```
$scope.changeLanguage = function( lang ) {
    $scope.lang = lang === 'ar-sa' ? 'de_AR' : 'de_EN';
    $translate.use($scope.lang);
}
$scope.changeLanguage($window.navigator.language || $window.navigator.userLanguage);
```

View:

```
<div class="language">
    <a href="#" ng-click="changeLanguage(lang === 'de_AR' ? 'de_EN' : 'ar-sa')">
       <img ng-src="images/{{ lang === 'de_AR' ? 'arabic.png' : 'en-english-language-browser-function-512.png' }}" />
    </a>
</div>
```

What I did in the above example is to check if the language (Which is the returned value of `$window.navigator.language || $window.navigator.userLanguage`) is equal to `'ar-sa'` and if so, set the language to its matching i18n code.

Comment: thank you. My default language is based on browser setting. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43493019/dynamic-language-selection-in-angularjs/43493249#43493249

Comment: Thanks. I am not able to click the img. a href="#" it should be # only?

Comment: I just added the relevant HTML for the view, can you try it? Note that I changed the `ngClick` to `ng-click="changeLanguage(lang === 'de_AR' ? 'de_EN' : 'ar-sa')"`